# how can I calculate Poisson's ratio of graphene monolayer (2D material)

Tags: elasticity

How can I calculate the Poisson's ratio of graphene monolayer, where I got the in-plane stiffness along the x-axis? most of the papers use this equation

ES = b1Ꜫx2 + b2Ꜫy2 + b3ꜪxꜪy

to calculate the Poisson's ratio beside they plot this diagram, so how can I get this diagram?

[image]

Comment: There's a general expression to convert the 2D elastic constants matrix which includes C11, C22, C66, C12, C16, C26 into an angle dependent Poisson's ratio in this paper (https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jpcc.1c06462). I'd recommend checking how the 2D elastic constants matrix will look like for graphene (hexagonal lattice) here (https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2053-1583/ab2ef3) to get the nonzero components to be plugged into the Poisson's ratio expression.